# Open Source firmware for e-ink book reader

Tags: linux, free-software, firmware

Is there any open source version of firmware for ebook readers or maybe project like RockBox?

AFAIK most of e-ink readers runs linux, so maybe exists at least one model of e-reader with an open specification and/or drivers for which you can build your own custom linux ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there [exists](http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/fun-e-ink-x-and-gumstix) some information. The [driver](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/include/video/broadsheetfb.h) for the e-ink display is broadsheetfb. However, attempting to do it is probably non-trivial since this is not something that is commonly done.

That said, **good luck** and if you succeed in this, please post details!

Answer (score 1):

There is a project called OpenInkPot (http://morgue.openinkpot.org), which seems to be quite dead now (see http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?s=6a5352bf5e25c68ecc88d06ce5f7eb21&t=202855). It is still usable on some older devices.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project called fred.ink
https://fread.ink/

Last changes 25.11.2019...